# Stream data from OrientDB

Tags: php, orientdb

I would like to create a website that shows analysis of my Odb database. Therefore I need to extract data from orientdb, in a "live way" i.e connect and open the database via php, query my database and stock into variables the results. I found one API written in php that is supposed to stream data from Odb but it's not working.

Do you know if there is any way to do like the php command mysqli (that connect to mysql and allows you to query the database) but with orientDb ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I hope will be of help, to these two links:

- [OrientDB-PHP](https://github.com/AntonTerekhov/OrientDB-PHP)
- [Graph-in-php-through-OrientDB](http://odino.org/graph-in-php-through-orientdb/)

the guides are shown to connect to OrientDB via php.